# Should intermediate certificates be added as TrustAnchors when validating certificte chains?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I am trying to verify a chain of certificates that I have generated on my own, and I seem to get correct results but I am unsure if I am doing it the right way.

Say I have a chain of `Intermediate -> Intermediate -> Leaf`. I don't care about the root, I want to verify up to a certain point in a chain. This could be the root, or just a snippet of a longer chain, provided that it is intact.

To clarify;  I want to verify that chain regardless of the ultimate root. `Root -> Intermediate 1 -> Intermediate 2 -> Leaf` should be valid, as well as only `Intermediate 1 -> Intermediate 2 -> Leaf`. The only difference here should probably (?) be what is considered the TrustAnchor.

To do this, I have followed [this Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#PKIXValidationExample).

Here's my code snippet:

```java
public boolean validateChain(final X509Certificate... certificates) {
    try {
        final CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");


        final X509Certificate intermediateCertificate = certificates[0];
        final X509Certificate leaf = certificates[1];

        final List<X509Certificate> path = Collections.singletonList(leaf);
        final CertPath certPath = certificateFactory.generateCertPath(path);

        Set<TrustAnchor> anchors = new HashSet<>();
        anchors.add(new TrustAnchor(intermediateCertificate, null));

        final X509Certificate root = this.certificate;
        anchors.add(new TrustAnchor(root, null));

        PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(anchors);
        params.setRevocationEnabled(false);

        CertPathValidator validator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
        validator.validate(certPath, params);

        return true;
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
        LOG.error("Could not validate certificate chain", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Never mind the rudimentary array handling, I will improve on that. This implementation assumes a base class of mine has been implemented and that is always the root against which the supplied certificates are validated.

Is this the right way to do it? I don't really understand the distinction between a TrustAnchor and the certificates placed in the CertPath.

If I add the certificate named `intermediateCertificate` to the construction of the CertPath, the execution fails with:

> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: subject/issuer name chaining check failed

Say if I wanted to verify a chain with 10 certificates, should only the leaf certificate be placed in the CertPath and all other certificates above in the chain are considered TrustAnchors?

If anyone could shine a light on this distinction I'd be very grateful.

**Additional information edit:**

I know my chain is valid because I have verified my entire chain using OpenSSL. This is my entire chain, where each file contains only the public part of the certificate.

```sh
openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -untrusted intermediate1.pem -untrusted intermediate2.pem leaf.pem
```

I have also verified a partial chain:

```sh
openssl verify -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted intermediate1.pem -trusted intermediate2.pem leaf.pem
```

Both of these respond with `leaf.pem: OK`.

Comment: You speak only of intermediates. Do you have the root CA in your trust anchors?

Comment: @Gimby the root is not present in the trust anchors. As I mentioned, I want to verify that chain regardless of the ultimate root. `Root -> Intermediate 1 -> Intermediate 2 -> Leaf` should be valid, as well as only `Intermediate 1 -> Intermediate 2 -> Leaf`, since it is still an intact and verifiable chain.

Comment: Anchors seem to be the records inside `cacerts`. The ones that you trust. You can place intermediate certificates into `cacerts` and the validation should (I didn't check) stop there and not check the root.

Comment: You can use anything in the chain as the trust anchor, but why you wouldn't use the root is a mystery.

Comment: @user207421 Well, we have a PKI accessed by credentials where I know beforehand that my intermediate certificate has the right origin. OpenSSL supports this verification scenario, so it can't be that strange can it?

Comment: But you also know that the root is trusted. That's the meaning of 'right origin'. It's simply space economy to only store the trusted roots.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to answer my question because I just figured it out and it was an error on my side, but I also can answer the question posed.

*No*, intermediate certificates should not be added as trust anchors. The trust anchor is the common denominator from where you will trust all certificates.

If I am reading the [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-3.2) right, a root of trust when dealing with x509 certificates is simply a public key which you verify that underlying certificate chains reach that origin and follows the given constraints. I.e. it doesn't matter if your trust anchor is a root or not.

The snippet in my original post is correct, but I have a static initializer in my class which sets the security provider:

```java
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

To get my code to work, I had to set the same provider for the certificate factory. Here's the full working sample in case anyone is in need of it:

```java
public boolean validateChain(final X509Certificate... certificates) {
    try {
        final CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); // <--- Here's the addition

        final List<X509Certificate> path = Arrays.asList(certificates);
        final CertPath certPath = certificateFactory.generateCertPath(path);

        PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(Set.of(new TrustAnchor(this.certificate, null)));
        params.setRevocationEnabled(false);

        CertPathValidator validator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
        validator.validate(certPath, params);

        return true;
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
        LOG.error("Could not validate certificate chain", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this case, `this.certificate` is the root. I have a class that creates an object to handle CA capable certificates.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to validate the chain. We are good to validate only the leaf in most use-cases. The problem of trusting root or any intermediate is you are trusting all the certificate issued by those intermediate and the root.

Let us take for example, if you trust a certificate issued by Let's Encrypt, and you trust the Root CA and the intermediate, the risk of trusting all certificates issues by Let's Encrypt certificates.

It is important to **validate the Chain** and **only trust leaf** if you want to make sure you are trusting the communication. `TrustAnchors` are only for

> most-trusted CA

So It is fine to trust the leaf. This is just my opinion.

Comment: The whole meaning of PKI is that if you trust the root you trust what they issue. That's a feature, not a problem.

Comment: I am using self signed certificates without a public root in an iot environment, so I don't think these precautions apply here. But I think if you don't trust the root, why use the certificates at all?